# My tensorflow 2.0 custom model is not receiving the shape or values I expect

Tags: tensorflow, deep-learning, tensorflow2.0

I'm in the process of converting my pytorch models into tensorflow 2.0, so I'm still getting used to it. I have mostly gone off the API, I made a custom model, and defined it's `call` method with argument `inputs`:

```py
class CustomModel(tf.keras.Model):
    <... init...>
    def call(self, inputs):
        print("inputs: ", inputs)
        self.sequential_convolution(inputs)
```

The `sequential_convolution` is a `keras.Sequential` of multiple convolution related layers. I can create the model object, compile it. It is variable length on both the output and input

```py
model = CustomModel(inputs=tf.keras.Input(shape=(None, vdim)))
model.compile(optimizer=optimizer, loss=loss_func, metrics=[calc_accuracy])

for x, y in dataset:
    print("x.shape: ", x.shape)
    print("y.shape: ", y.shape)
    model.fit(x, y, batch_size=1)
```

Where the shapes are `x.shape: (244, 161)` and `y.shape: (40,)`. Both are Tensorflow tensors created from numpy arrays with `tf.convert_to_tensor()`.

But when the model's `call` method prints the inputs, I get the following:

```py
Tensor("input_1_1:0", shape=(None, 161), dtype=float32)
```

Which I should point out is not the `Input` defined on the model, this input is calculated from the actual input provided in the `model.fit()`, I manually changed the numbers to see what the causes were...

Which then ultimately leads to the stack trace:

```py
        x = self.sequential_conv(inputs)
    /usr/local/lib/python3.6/dist-packages/tensorflow_core/python/autograph/impl/api.py:396 converted_call
        return py_builtins.overload_of(f)(*args)

    TypeError: 'NoneType' object is not callable
```

This error occurs in a function deemed internal use only, but not able to ascertain what the cause of my problem is.

As I can't find much information on the matter, I feel that it's most likely something simple I haven't done, but I'm not sure. Any help would be great...

Comment: If I remember correctly, you feed batches of data to Keras models, so you probably need to reshape the input tensor to be `(1,244,161)`.

Comment: Well I reshaped it to having an imput tensor of `(1, i, j)`, but I still have the same stack trace, with the printed tensor as `Tensor("input_1_1:0", shape=(None, 244, 161), dtype=float32)`, seems we are the right track though

Comment: To use the convolution, I guess a `(1,i,j,1)` shape would be expected.

Comment: Please edit your answer to provide the output of `model.summary()`

Comment: I am currently unable to run `.summary()` as it says you first need to `.build()` or `.fit()`.. I think you are correct in the shape though. I removed the layers from the keras `Sequential`, and I am getting incorrect dimensions, I will play around with the dimensions until I can figure something out more meaningful.